# d3.tsv error log "syntax error {}"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, csv

I've made a map loading topojson and tsv.

```
queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "data/ita_com2.json")
      .defer(d3.json, "data/infra_topo.json")
      .defer(d3.json, "data/corridoi_topo.json")
      .defer(d3.json, "data/pend.php")
      .defer(d3.tsv, "data/popres91-11.tsv")
      .await(ready);

  function ready(error, base, infra, corr, dati, popres) {
    console.log(error);
    ....
```

It works great on localhost, but when I move it online the tsv isn't loaded!
http://www.danielepennati.com/prove/mapping/ita_pop_pend.html
If you look at the console.log you can see the console.log(error) output that is:

```
SyntaxError {}
```

and the error caused by the unloading of the tsv

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
```

I really can't understand why I'm getting this error! on localhost it works fine and online if I load the tsv in the console I get it without any problem:

```
d3.tsv("data/data.tsv", function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Any idea about?
thanks
daniele

Comment: It sounds like you haven't uploaded all of the files correctly.

Comment: Thanks Lars. The file is not loading correctly is the "data/popres91-11.tsv" passed to the "ready" function link "popres". if you go here http://www.danielepennati.com/prove/mapping/data/popres91-11.tsv you can get the file without any issue... and if you use d3.tsv("data/popres91-11.tsv", function(error, data) {... the file load. I think the issue is in some way related to the .defer() but I don't known what to think...

Comment: Well, does `error` contain anything?

Comment: Loading `data/pend.php` returns `Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)[]`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How do you get the mysql error?

Comment: Get It!!! Thanks! the issue on the pend.php blocked the loading of the next file... I didn't updated the data of the online database... no comment...

Comment: I opened your source and try to load all data files listed in it. Only php failed.